# Can I directly use the Qt and GTK+ libraries I saw in the Update Manager?

Tags: gtk, qt, libraries

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop today, and when I was updating it using the Update Manager, I saw it downloading qt and gtk libraries. Does that mean I can use them directly? Or will I need to download them from their respective sites and build them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to build anything. Maybe those libraries were pulled because they're dependencies of some other package you installed through Update Manager.

So i wouldn't worry about that, chances are those libraries are already installed on your system.

Comment: I didnt add any thing to the update manager, as soon as it finished installing the OS, I entered Update Manager. Another question, how can I use these libraries, like where are they located?

Comment: Depending on the library they could be in `/lib` or `/usr/lib/`, if you want to know the location of files installed by a package just try `sudo dpkg -L packagename`

Comment: I want to include the wx library as global variable in Code::Blocks, but I need the base location of the wx library, I used the command you gave me above, but it gave me the list of files owned by the package. Is there a way to get the exact location of the base wx library?

Comment: You can try `sudo mlocate wx`